# What am I doing wrong in this Python example code from GitHub?

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to run the quickstart examples from this code on GitHub: https://github.com/brain-research/deep-molecular-massspec

I've downloaded and unzipped the library. Then I open a Bash terminal in that folder, copy each line from the quickstart example and hit enter:

```
TARGET_PATH_NAME=/tmp/massspec_predictions
```

Then:

```
python make_train_test_split.py \
--main_sdf_name=testdata/test_14_mend.sdf 
--replicates_sdf_name=testdata/test_2_mend.sdf 
--output_master_dir=$TARGET_PATH_NAME/spectra_tf_records 
--alsologtostderr
```

This gives the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "make_train_test_split.py", line 451, in 
app.run(main)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
_run_main(main, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
sys.exit(main(argv))
File "make_train_test_split.py", line 400, in main
tf.gfile.MkDir(FLAGS.output_master_dir)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 409, in create_dir
create_dir_v2(dirname)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 427, in create_dir_v2
pywrap_tensorflow.CreateDir(compat.as_bytes(path), status)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in exit
c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /tmp/massspec_predictions/spectra_tf_records; No such file or directory
```

The temp files don't seem to be being created. I'm not sure why this is. Can someone smarter than me explain why this is and how to resolve it?

Comment: do you have the folder massspec_predictions already under tmp?

Comment: You may have to `mkdir /tmp/massspec_predictions` manually first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `massspec_predictions` is missing. Create the folder at `/tmp/massspec_predictions`. You can do this straight from the terminal:

```
mkdir /tmp/massspec_predictions
```